# Uncaught ReferenceError: functionis not defined error, why?

Tags: javascript, html, backend

I have been trying my hands on javascript and it works but suddenly has stopped working i.e. js functions are not getting called. I have placed both .js and html file on desktop but still not working.

Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: funcLoadImage is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

and this error could be for any function i am calling.

JS:

```
function funcLoadImage() {
  document.getElementById("img1").src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/Hopetoun_falls.jpg"
}

function funcMath(type, data) {
  if (type == 1) {
    document.getElementById("img1").alt = 'Type 1'
  }

  if (type == 2) {
    document.getElementById("img1").alt = 'Type 2'
  }
}

funtion funcDate() {
  document.getElementById("img1").alt = 'date add'
}
```

Html Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<img id="img1" src="" alt="No image loaded" width="50%" height="50%"/>
<button id="btn1" width="20%" height="20%" onclick='funcLoadImage()'>Load Image</button>
<button id="btn2" width="20%" height="20%" onmouseover="this.style.width='60%'" onmouseout="this.style.width='20%'">Write Doc</button>
<button id="btn3" width="20%" height="20%" onclick='funcMath(1,4)'>Calculate</button>
<button id="btn4" width="20%" height="20%" onclick='this.innerHTML=Date()'>Display Date</button>



<p>

</p>
<script src="script1.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If this is your actual code then you have a typo here `funtion funcDate`  which results into a syntax error, so the whole content of `script1.js` is not evaluated because of that syntax error.

Comment: thanks sir. Put it in answer box and i will mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this.............

```js
function funcLoadImage() {
  document.getElementById("img1").src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/Hopetoun_falls.jpg";
}

function funcMath(type, data) {
  if (type == 1) {
    document.getElementById("img1").alt = 'Type 1';
  }

  if (type == 2) {
    document.getElementById("img1").alt = 'Type 2';
  }
}

function funcDate() {
  document.getElementById("img1").alt = 'date add';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<img id="img1" src="" alt="No image loaded" width="50%" height="50%"/>
<button id="btn1" width="20%" height="20%" onclick='funcLoadImage()'>Load Image</button>
<button id="btn2" width="20%" height="20%" onmouseover="this.style.width='60%'" onmouseout="this.style.width='20%'">Write Doc</button>
<button id="btn3" width="20%" height="20%" onclick='funcMath(1,4)'>Calculate</button>
<button id="btn4" width="20%" height="20%" onclick='this.innerHTML=Date()'>Display Date</button>



<p>

</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script1.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Explain why this solves the OPs problem. Just pasting code is not helpful, unless you say what the OP did wrong.

Comment: your code has lots of syntax error...like you didn't put semicolon in end of any statement...
automate semicolon insertion cause lots of error..so try to put yourself...

Comment: The only syntax error was the `funtion`. Omitting semicolons is **not** a syntax error. If omitting semicolons is good or bad style is something you can argue much about, both have their pros and cons.

Comment: yep..but i want to say sometime cause error...
i know function is the error in above code..and i correct that in my code above

Comment: Yes but you wrote `[...]your code has lots of syntax error...like you didn't put semicolon[...]` which is misleading, because there are not lots of syntax errors it is just one error, and the missing semicolons are no errors, they are optional and not required.